# When you develop a library in Java, how does it become a "standard" library?

Tags: java, standards

Suppose that I developed a library and published it as a project. What makes my library a "standard" library for Java and be in next JDK version?

Comment: Standard library --> library that comes along with the JDK. That's why it's "standard" -- *everyone* has it.

Comment: @user3580294 JSF is a standard in Java EE and **does not come** with the JDK. Similar with JCache.

Comment: It may be a standard, and it may be a library, but it's not a standard library.

Comment: @DavidConrad Are standart libraries all developed by Oracle?

Comment: (The word is "standard".) No, the Joda Time library was developed by Stephen Colebourne before being adopted (largely) as the java.time API.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From what I've witnessed, this happens when your framework helps the Java community so much that it can be moved into a specification in form of JSR. Then, a set of interfaces is developed and, usually, your library becomes the first implementation, or the implementation is added directly into the JDK.

Notorious examples of this:

- Hibernate/Eclipse Link -> JPA
- Seam -> CDI
- Ehcache/Infinispan -> JCache
- Joda Time -> Java 8 Date Time API

Note that in all these cases, what becomes the standard is the specification, the JSR. The library is not standard, it is just an implementation of the standard. Also, from these examples, they didn't give born to the JSR that easily, it take some years to the frameworks to get mature enough before generating these specifications.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. So, I need to advertise it and make it used by a large audience. Then, Oracle will hear about it and decide to put it in next JDK. Did I understand correctly?

Comment: That's...approximately true, but you should also look at how old each of those libraries were before they got adapted for the JDK.  You're not likely to make the "next" JDK, or even the one after, even if you come up with the Next Big Thing.

Comment: @cagirici You would start advertising it as your product (free or commercial). Then, the [community](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/community/index.html) itself will decide if your product is *good enough* to become a standard in form of JSR. As pointed out by LouisWasserman, this doesn't happen that fast, it may take years to happen.

Answer (score 1):

Some libraries which are more or less known in Java community are not parts of JDK. There is such thing as [Apache Maven](http://maven.apache.org/) which is using huge repositories full of different libraries. As soon as your library is really popular (and published in a repository available for everyone, although not maven official), you may want to contact representatives to suggest your library to be included in the so-called *maven central repository*.